# Rails 3.0.7 and Mongodb integration

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongomapper

I want to create my first web application in rails with mongodb but I am having some troubles with proper integration. Firstly, here is my database.yml file:

```
development:
  adapter: mongodb
  database: mongo_development
  host: localhost

test:
  adapter: mongodb
  database: mongo_test
  host: localhost

production:
  adapter: mongodb
  database: mongo_production
  host: localhost
```

In one of several tutorials I saw a activerecord model equivalent - MongoMapper. For example my User model:

```
class User
  include MongoMapper::Document

  key :name, String
  key :age,  Integer

  many :books
end
```

I also added mongodb.rb to config/initializers:

```
db_config = YAML::load(File.read(RAILS_ROOT + "/config/database.yml"))

if db_config[Rails.env] &&
  db_config[Rails.env]['adapter'] == 'mongodb'
  mongo = db_config[Rails.env]
  MongoMapper.connection = Mongo::Connection.new(mongo['hostname'])
  MongoMapper.database = mongo['database']
end
```

I've created controller for the user:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def index
    user = User.new(:name => 'Brandon')
    user.books.build(:name => 'Programming', :started => 10.years.ago)
    user.save!
    puts User.where(:name => 'Brandon').first    
  end
end
```

But I'm still getting an error :

```
Please install the mongodb adapter: `gem install activerecord-mongodb-adapter` (no such file to load -- active_record/connection_adapters/mongodb_adapter)
```

My installed gems:

```
 abstract (1.0.0)
 actionmailer (3.0.7)
 actionpack (3.0.7)
 activemodel (3.0.7)
 activerecord (3.0.7)  
 activeresource (3.0.7)
 activesupport (3.0.8, 3.0.7)
 ....
 mongo (1.3.1)
 mongo_mapper (0.9.1)
 rails (3.0.7)
 railties (3.0.7)
 rake (0.9.2)
 rubygems-update (1.8.5)
```

Can anyone help?

---

UPDATE

I removed mongodb.rb initializer, database.yml and used `rails g mongo_mapper:config`.It created file mongo.yml:

```
defaults: &defaults
   host: 127.0.0.1
   port: 27017

development:
   <<: *defaults
   database: mongo_db_app_development

test:
   <<: *defaults
   database: mongo_db_app_tests

# set these environment variables on your prod server
production:
   <<: *defaults
   database: mongo_db_app
   username: <%= ENV['MONGO_USERNAME'] %>
   password: <%= ENV['MONGO_PASSWORD'] %>
```

But i got error: `No such file or directory - /home/adm/NetBeansProjects/MongoDBApp/config/database.yml`

So I copied a contents of mongo.yml file to database.yml and I got error:

`ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified 
database configuration does not specify adapter`

Answer (score 3):

MongoMapper is a full replacement for ActiveRecord--it's not simply an adapter.

Run `rails g mongo_mapper:config` and that will create a mongo.yml config file for MongoMapper and you won't need the mongodb.rb initializer.  Also, you'll have to remove the `adapter: mongodb` from your database.yml, otherwise ActiveRecord will keep looking for a non-existant mongodb adapter.

Answer (score 1):

I answered a different question before on integrating mongodb on top of another db in this question:

[How to configure MongoMapper and ActiveRecord in same Ruby Rails Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6756475/how-to-configure-mongomapper-and-activerecord-in-same-ruby-rails-project/6757749#6757749)

You can follow that and leave out the part that applies to ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 0):

I recently wrote an article to build rails 3.0 project on mongodb.[Rails 3.0 and mongoDB](http://tech-read.com/2011/09/12/rails-3-mongdb-mongomapper-beginner-tutorial/)

Hope this is useful..